# How to get order data in salesPlaceOrderAfter observer

Tags: magento-enterprise, checkout, event-observer

Amazon payments api requires to send session post variable, grand total and increment id. How to get order data in salesPlaceOrderAfter observer

```
class Amazon_Payments_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object
{

public function salesPlaceOrderAfter($observer)
{
    $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
        Mage::log('post salesPlaceOrderAfter');
        Mage::log($post);
        //$orderData = $observer->getQuote()->getData();
       $orderData = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        Mage::log('orderData');
        Mage::log($orderData);
        //$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        //Mage::log($checkout);




    $payment_method = $post['payment']['method'];
    if($payment_method=='pay'){
        $session = $post['billing']['session'];
        $access_token = $post['billing']['access_token'];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The event is dispatched like this:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_place_after', array('order'=>$this));
```

So check first that you are observing the correct event:
sales_order_place_after

(your method naming could indicate you have the name the other way around, salesPlaceOrderAfter)

I would suggest logging the debug output with

```
$orderData = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
Mage::log('orderData');
Mage::log($orderData->debug());
```

and getting the data with (or adjust to order currency by removing base)

```
$orderData->getIncrementId();
$orderData->getBaseGrandTotal();
```

Answer (score 6):

we have to access the grand total and increment id then you can also use below one

```
class Amazon_Payments_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object
{
 public function salesPlaceOrderAfter($observer)
 {
  /*your code*/
   Mage::log('order Grand Total:'.$observer->getOrder()->getBaseGrandTotal());
   Mage::log('increment id:'.$observer->getOrder()->getIncrementId());
  /*your code*/
 }
}
```